# How can i check if an item is part of a specific menu [Joomla 3.3]

Tags: php, joomla, menu

i already know how to parse id/name and stuff from my current/active menu-item, but i want to know if it's part of a specific menu for example:

I have this Menu with the name "mainmenu" and type "mainmenu": Home | About | Contact | Testing

If i click on About i want to know if About is part of "mainmenu" - how can i do that?

like this:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$activeitem = $menu->getActive()->id;
// And now the if-statement - which asks if activeitem is part of "mainmenu" and if yes do that, and if not do that...
```

I hope you know what i mean...

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check menutype using below code -

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu = $app->getMenu();
$menutype = $menu->getActive()->menutype;
if($menutype =='mainmenu'){//check if active menu part of 'mainmenu'

}
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Thats so easy... why didn't i get this?